# BinaryWriter not taking substitute args

Tags: c#, .net, substitution

I'm trying to write binary user data into  a .data file and for bw.Write() the substitutes {0},{1},{2},{3} cannot be used because of it being mistakened to be a parameter to the method.

Is there a work around to write this data to the file but still substituting variables like in Console.Write("Hello {0}", name)

When I hover over the error it says

> No overload for method 'Write' takes 5 arguments

```
public static void WriteUser(String path, String user, String auth, String pass, DateTime date)
    {

        try
        {
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("mydata", FileMode.Open));

            bw.Write("{0}{\nAuth:{1}\nPass:{2}\nDateCreated:{3}", user, auth, pass, date);
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n Cannot write to file.");
            return;
        }
        bw.Close();

    }
```

Comment: If you cannot use a StringWriter instead of the BinaryWriter for some reason, you will want to use the `String.Format()` function to substitute the variables into a string, and then agree on an encoding, for example ASCII, to convert the string into a stream of bytes for the binary format.

Comment: I have looked at tutorials in BinaryWriter and I just need to provide a string to the bw.Write() function/method but I want to add substitutes to the String like you do with Console.Write("Bye {0}", name)

Answer (score 3):

Just call `string.Format` yourself:

```
bw.Write(string.Format("{0}{\nAuth:{1}\nPass:{2}\nDateCreated:{3}", user, auth, pass, date));
```

Although if you're using C# 6, you can make this cleaner using interpolated strings:

```
bw.Write($"{user}{{\nAuth:{auth}\nPass:{pass}\nDateCreated:{date}");
```

Note that if you're trying to write text, I'd just use `StreamWriter` - or better yet, just call `File.WriteAllText`:

```
public static void WriteUser(String path, String user, String auth, String pass, DateTime date)
{
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(
            "mydata",
            $"{user}{{\nAuth:{auth}\nPass:{pass}\nDateCreated:{date}");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n Cannot write to file.");
        return;
    }
}
```